# Plot multi-series Dataframe using Streamlit + Altair

Tags: python, pandas, plot, altair, streamlit

I have the following DF `elo_df`

```
date        Person1 Person2 Person3 Person4 Person5 Person6                     
2020-12-31  1500    1500    1500    1500    1500    1500
2021-01-01  1480    1506    1506    1500    1506    1500
2021-01-06  1513    1495    1495    1490    1515    1490
2021-01-08  1506    1502    1502    1490    1508    1490
```

and I'd like to plot it using Altair and have it zoomable and interactive. Moreover, I'd like to be able to set Y-domain to `[1350, 1600]`. I have a list of `players_names=["Person1",..., "Person6"]` that I would like to use, in case there is one more person.

This is what I've done so far

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st

[...part where I obtain elo_df...]

k = alt.Chart(elo_df.reset_index()).transform_fold(
    players_names).mark_line().encode(
        alt.X('date'),
        alt.Y('value', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[1350, 1600])),
        color='variable',
    )

    st.altair_chart(k)
```

This leads me to the following error:
`ValueError: variable encoding field is specified without a type; the type cannot be inferred because it does not match any column in the data.`

I haven't quite figured out, even after reading the documentation, the reason of `transform_fold` and how to use it next, so any new way to explain it would be appreciated.

Comment: consider changing the format of the dataframe. Having a column per person doesn't seem like the right format for the data.   try something like `{"date": "2020-12-31", "value":  1500, "person": 1}`. chose date for x, value for y, and person for color. Typically `color` would break it into separate lines to plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altair uses pandas to determine which data type to use when plotting the data. For any data not part of a pandas dataframe, such as data from a URL or a column from a transform, you will need to [explicitly specify what type the data is](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html#encoding-data-types):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd


elo_df = pd.read_clipboard()
players_names=elo_df.filter(like='Person').columns.tolist()
chart = alt.Chart(elo_df.reset_index()).transform_fold(
    players_names).mark_line().encode(
        alt.X('date:T'),
        alt.Y('value:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[1350, 1600])),
        color='key:N',
    )

chart
```

[image]